# Is it safe to delete the pack files from .git/objects/?

Tags: git, github

I'm now planning to archive/deprecate a repository and move it to an external drive. However, some large pack files in .git/objects/pack could not be transferred because they were larger than 4GB. I'm aware that directly deleting the pack files would rewrite the history, but I'm wondering whether it is fine to just remove the files if I am sure that I'm not going to retrieve any files from the history in the future. Are there any other drawbacks of directly removing the whole `pack` folder? I assume that other files in the repo won't be influenced, but just their backups. Is this correct?

Comment: It won't rewrite history; it will *corrupt* it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do that, you'll make the whole thing useless as a git repo, in which case you might as well remove all of `.git`.

If your concern is files over 4GiB (presumably because of FAT filesystems), how about using `git repack -ad --max-pack-size=3G`, which will rewrite all of the objects into new packs, ensuring that none of the pack files is too large?

Answer (score 2):

> but I'm wondering whether it is fine to just remove the files if I am sure that I'm not going to retrieve any files from the history in the future

It is just fine if you are never going to want any of the history again — because it will destroy that history, forever. In fact, if you are never going to want any of the history again, just delete the *.git* directory and all its contents. The enclosing folder (which you are about to move to an external drive) won't be a "repository" any more, but it will contain the current state of the project.

Comment: Regarding this, I have a naive question. If I delete .git folder and execute `git init`. Will I be able to push commits in the future if I really need to? Will this wipe out the previous commits? How does `git init` change things in this case?

Comment: `git init` will create a new repository in this place with none of the history or configuration of the current one. What you're left with is *literally* just a snapshot of the content whatever branch/tag/commit you had checked out when you deleted `.git` (which may or may not be `main`/`master`, btw).

Comment: `Will I be able to push commits in the future` in this hypothetical scenario where would you be pushing commits _to_ ? If you only care about the current state, and not history, a (bare) shallow clone OR deleting the .git directory are the simplest options.

Comment: I meant pushing commits to the remote repository on GitHub if that makes sense.

Comment: If you are keeping the GitHub repo - or any other copy of the repo - why not just outright delete the local copy? Alternatively: no it does not make sense :).

Comment: I totally agree with that. If you have a GitHub repo, why not throw away the _whole_ folder? GitHub is keeping a copy for you. And you can re-clone at any time.